# Compact family of Lip functions under the sup norm metric, proof verification.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, self-learning, compactness

Hi everyone I'd like to know if the following is correct, I'd appreciate your opinion and also any suggestion to improve my argument. Thanks in advance for your time.

> If $(K,d)$ is a compact metric space and $u\in K$ show that for any finite $M$ and $\alpha\in (0,1]$, $\mathcal{F}=\{f\in \text{Lip}(\alpha,M): \lvert f(u)\rvert\ \le M \}$ is compact with respect to the $d_{sup}$, where $\text{Lip}(\alpha,M)$ is the set of all real valued function on $S$, s.t. $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert\le Md(x,y)^{\alpha}$

Proof:
$\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly equicontinuous. Given $\varepsilon>0$, let $\delta =[\varepsilon/{(M+1)]}^{1/\alpha}$.  Then for $x,y\in K$, $d(x,y)<\delta$ and $f\in \mathcal{F}$ we thus have $\rvert f(x)-f(y)\lvert\le Md(x,y)^{\alpha}<\varepsilon$. Also  $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly bounded, since $\lvert f(u)\rvert\ \le M $ for any $u\in K$, hence $\sup_{u\in K}\lvert f(u)\rvert\le M$. By Arzela- Ascoli $\mathcal{F}$ is totally bounded by $d_{sup}$.

To conclude, we will show that $\mathcal{F}$ is complete. It sufficient to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed, since $\mathcal{F}\subset C_b(K)$ which is complete [$C_b(K)$ are the continuous bounded functions from $K$ to $\mathbb{R}$].

Suppose $f_n\to f$ for $f_n\in \mathcal{F}$. Given $\varepsilon>0$ for a sufficient large $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $d_{sup}(f,f_n)<\varepsilon$. Let $x\in K$, then $\lvert f(x)-f_n(x) \rvert \le d_{sup}(f,f_n)$, it follows that $\vert f(x)\rvert <\lvert f_i(x) \rvert+\varepsilon\le M+\varepsilon $, since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary then $\lvert f(x) \rvert\le M $.

Also we have the following:
 \begin{align}\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert \le \lvert f(x)-f_n(x) \rvert+\lvert f_n(x)-f_n(y) \rvert +\lvert f_n(y)-f(y) \rvert \\< Md(x,y)^{\alpha}+2\varepsilon\end{align}

Thus $\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert \le Md(x,y)^{\alpha}$ and hence $ \mathcal{F}$ is closed as we claimed.

Is the above OK? this is the version of Arzela Ascoli that I use

[image]

Nobody could help me, please?

Comment: Your proof seems correct to me. The key in here is that functions in that class have the same $Lip-\alpha$ constant.otherwise proof wouldnt work.You dont get equicontinuity whatsoever.which is crucial in A-A theorem.

Comment: @BigM I proved uniformly equicontinuity, which in this case is  sufficient, because $K$ is metric and its open set are generated by the balls, so is automatically equicontinuous. Thanks for take your time and read all. One more thing: This version of AA is slightly different that the version which I found in other books, do you know besides Dudley which other uses the same version of AA or where I can found a proof of the equivalence?

Comment: I looked at Willard's general topology, the only topology textbook I have .it doesnt give us the version you are looking for. but you can see the proper version in [here](http://www.mth.msu.edu/~shapiro/pubvit/Downloads/ArzNotes/ArzNotes.pdf)